# Debugging LINQ on Windows Phone

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone programming, and am trying to get a simple Application to run.
However, I have difficulties with debugging.

On the creation of the Database I want to insert some default data:

```
        using (DODataContext db = new DODataContext(DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                // Create the local database.
                db.CreateDatabase();

                DateTime DateFields = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

                // Prepopulate the categories.
                db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new DOLanguage { Code = "EN", Name = "English", LastUpdate = DateFields });
                db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new DOLanguage { Code = "FR", Name = "French", LastUpdate = DateFields });
                db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new DOLanguage { Code = "ES", Name = "Spanish", LastUpdate = DateFields });

                db.MenuItems.InsertOnSubmit(new DOMenuItem { Id = 3, Title = "Test 3", LastUpdate = DateFields, Level = 1, Action = "article/1", CommonId = 1, Section = "", Icon = "", Published = true, _languageId = 1 });

                // Save categories to the database.
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

However, on 'db.MenuItems.InsertOnSubmit' the application crashes and I get the following console output (db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit works fine):

> The thread '' (0x18630716) has exited with code 0 (0x0). The
>   thread '' (0x183809e2) has exited with code 0 (0x0). The
>   thread '' (0x191d0b02) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

There is no info, and I have no idea what goes wrong. Anybody any suggestions how to debug this problem?

Comment: Is `Id` perhaps defined so that you can't store your own value in it? (something like primary key with auto increment)

Comment: The _languageId looks suspicious, should that be LanguageId?

Comment: I tried both, with and without id. The id was not setup to be auto incremental.

Comment: I removed the relations too, and still the same problem, so will take apart the whole class until I can find a way that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_languageId = 1`, it's is not there in the database yet when you're adding that menu.

You can do it many ways, for example save it in two shots,

```
db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new DOLanguage { Code = "EN", Name = "English", LastUpdate = DateFields });
                db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new DOLanguage { Code = "FR", Name = "French", LastUpdate = DateFields });
                db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new DOLanguage { Code = "ES", Name = "Spanish", LastUpdate = DateFields });
```

and then call `save changes` and that should work, also you probably should not have specify the id of the menu item.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But I now only load the language items into the DB, which works, and then by a button try to add a MenuItem and still it gives the same crash

Comment: Found a typo in the id value van MenuItem. Used Id once instead of _id... Stupid mistake